# Lumia 640 XL LTE

Tags: bluetooth

I have a new Ford Fiesta Zetec and although I can pair my phone to the car it does not stay there, hence every time I get out of the car for however long, I have to pair again when I get in. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: If you go to **settings** > **bluetooth** on your phone, does your car show as "paired"? (Bluetooth will need to be turned on for this, but the car doesn't need to be in range) Is the car paired to any other phones? Or is the car just forgeting the pairing to your phone?

Comment: Additionally, have you set the phone up for driving mode?

Comment: Why do you have to set the phone for driving mode.   Is that the key to all of this?

Comment: I don't think you have to, but when trying to diagnose a problem, it's helpful to know what is set up...

Comment: We have done a soft restart or reset not sure what it is called.    Dont hold your breath but it appears to be working as it should at the moment.   Any change to this (we will try the car again today) and I will come back to the forum.   Thank you very much for your help.